# Does botkit or botframework run on multi node cluster

Tags: bots, botframework

I am evaluating using Botkit or Micorsoft Botframework for developing a bot. I played with Botframework and read the documentation of Botkit. Its not clear to me if either of this framework will run on multi node setup (Meaning the bot is running on more than one node, behind a load balancer). This can be an issue specially when the bot is having dialog with the user that contains several conversations to and fro. It looks both, the botkit and botframework are storing the user session in the memory and that does not make distributed ready solution. Is there an open source solution that supports multi node bot framework?

Answer (score 0):

Bot Framework supports multi-node deployments by default. User and conversation state is stored in the Bot Connector "Bot Data" API when you use the default data provider.

Comment: what if i dont want to use botconnector? Also, if the the dialog is a waterfall dialog, how does bot api know what step of the waterfall the dialog is currently waiting for user response?